# How to add a large amount of records from Microsoft Office Access 2007 database into a list box control using the native C++ WIN32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-access, listbox

### How to add a large amount of records from *Microsoft Office Access 2007* database into a *list box* control using the *native C++ WIN32 API*?

Hello friends! I want to make a dictionary like Microsoft Encarta English Dictionary using the native C++ WIN32 API. My database is Microsoft Office Access 2007 format database which has 21,364 records (filled with vocabularies and their meanings). I want to add the vocabularies into a list box control using the "`CreateWindow`" function with the "`listbox`" window class name as fast as possible so that no one will get annoyed of waiting.

I am very much interested in the **OLE DB** database connection method as it is said to be the fastest of all other methods. I followed the OLE DB tutorial as given in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff965871%28v=office.14%29. Following the tutorial, I successfully connected to the database of **Microsoft Office Access 2007** format having 21,364 records and added the vocabularies into the list box using the "`SendMessage`" function with the "`LB_ADDSTRING`" message type within a "`for`" loop.

However, I feel that adding the **21,364 records** into the **list box** using the "`for`" loop takes a bit longer than someone could patiently wait. On the contrary, I am sure the *Microsoft Encarta English Dictionary* should be having millions of vocabularies and they all added into a list box so fast that someone would burst out with joy!

Can anyone please kindly tell me, guide me, show me with code examples how to speed up my adding *huge amount* of **Microsoft Office Access 2007** database records into a **list box** using the **native C++ WIN32 API**? I shall be very thankful!

Comment: Maybe they won't get annoyed at waiting, but anybody would be annoyed at having to scroll through 21,364 items in a single listbox. You may wish to consider changing the design of your user interface to make it more user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few steps you can take when/if you want to add a lot of records to a list box quickly.

1. pre-sort the data, and tell the list box *not* to sort the data.
2. Pe-allocate space for the data (MS recommends, but I see little difference from this).
3. Consider using a "virtual list box" -- owner draw the items on demand instead of inserting them to start with.

For ~20,000 items, the first will probably suffice. Doing a quick check of inserting 20,000 items into a list box with sorting turned off, I'm getting about a half second without doing any more than that, so while there is a pause while it's filled, it's not enough to be annoying unless it happens frequently (i.e., you destroy and re-fill the listbox frequently).

At the same time, I do feel obliged to point out that a listbox containing 20,000 items is never likely to qualify as a really great design. You probably want/need to do something to narrow down how much of that you really display to the user at any given time.